(Reference request) Asymptotic of generalized exponential integral
I'm interested in asymptotics of the integral
$$
f_a(x)=\int_1^{x} t^a e^t\,dt, \ a\in \mathbb R,
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.
Mathematica gives $f_a(x)\sim x^a e^{x}$, $x\to \infty$.
I didnt' find it in Abramiovits, Stegun, only integer values of $a$ are considered there. DLMF introduces an integral $E_p(z)$ generally, starts with complex arguments:
$$
E_{p}\left(z\right)=z^{p-1}\Gamma(1-p,z)=z^{p-1}\int_{z}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{p}}\,{d}t,\quad z,p\in \mathbb{C},
$$
not giving a reference for the last equality, and defines a principal value for the rhs.
Is there a reference for asymptotics for the special case of $f_a$ where the function in integral is positive without need to define $t^p$ for negative $t$ etc as the general formula requires?

Integration by parts can help
$$\int_1^x t^a e^t,dt=t^a e^t,\bigg|_1^x-a\int_1^x t^{a-1} e^t,dt=x^ae^x-e-at^{a-1} e^t,\bigg|_1^x+a(a-1)\int_1^x t^{a-2} e^t,dt$$
etc.

@Svyatoslav Thanks, the required asymptotics follows indeed, at least if $a>0$.  But I hoped to get a reference in order not to prove it.

Why do you need a reference? Depending on the venue for the paper, I might just claim it without proof...

Assume that $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$ and $x>0$. By performing the change of integration variable $t = {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}} s$ and using $(8.2.1)$ and $(8.2.3)$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
f_a (x) & = {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}(a + 1)} \int_{{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} }^{{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} x} {s^a {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s}  = {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}(a + 1)}\! \left( {\int_0^{{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} x} {s^a {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s}  - \int_0^{{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} } {s^a {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s} } \right)
\\ & = {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}(a + 1)} \!\left( {\gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} x) - \gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} )} \right)
\\ & = {\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}a}\! \left( {\Gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} x) - \Gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} )} \right) 
\end{align*}
By analytic continuation, $f_a(x)={\rm e}^{\pi {\rm i}a} \!\left( {\Gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} x) - \Gamma (a + 1,{\rm e}^{ - \pi {\rm i}} )} \right)$ holds for any complex $a$. Then, by using $\S8.11.\text{i}$, we deduce
$$
f_a (x) \sim x^a {\rm e}^x \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - a)_k }}{{x^k }}} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.
If you are happy with the leading order asymptotics, you can just use L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \cfrac{{\displaystyle\int_1^x {t^a {\rm e}^t {\rm d}t} }}{{x^a {\rm e}^x }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{x^a {\rm e}^x }}{{x^a {\rm e}^x  + ax^{a - 1} {\rm e}^x }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{1 + ax^{ - 1} }} = 1.
$$

thanks  L'Hôpital's rule is enough for me, and it works for $a<0$ too.
